# How is historical "average calorie consumption" data from eighty years ago estimated?

Tags: germany, food, post-war, statistics, methodology

I read an [article](http://www.spiegel.de/fotostrecke/hungerwinter-fringsen-gegen-den-weissen-tod-fotostrecke-144849.html) in a German news magazine today about the German post-war "hunger winters" of 1946-48.

The article cites very detailed statistics about average calorie consumption in Germany in 1936 (3,300), and from the chaotic post-war period (down to 770 at times) with slightly different data *for the major cities*.

That seems *awfully* detailed. How is this possible? How are these data calculated or estimated? What other data (food production, purchase data...) are they based on?

Comment: I can't read German, but I'd expect any article providing that kind of detail to contain some kind of note somewhere saying where it came from.

Comment: @T.E.D nope, our news magazines aren't in the habit unfortunately. The article *is* part pitch for a book on the topic, I assume that would have a sources section though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These numbers were not measured like "actual calories consumed". But the numbers cited are quite easily "calculated" – for the cities.

From the start of the war for Germany in 1939 there were [Lebensmittelmarken](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebensmittelmarke)/Lebensmittelkarten (something like "[ration stamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ration_stamp)") given out to avoid the inequality and other problems associated with getting enough food and keeping the people quiet when the Rübenwinter (beet root winter) caused unrest in 1917.

These ration stamps were closely calculated according to the calories that could be bought with them. That was officially estimated to come down to 1550 kcal for the [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_Joe) [consumer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Normalverbraucher).

But this picture is hugely misleading since the people in the cities were wholly dependent on external supplies for food and the farmers still had more or less full access to many things they produced themselves. On the other hand the planned for foods could not be organised, transported, distributed as planned.

So you have an officially stated goal, the official prohibition to buy or sell basically anything containing calories and the statistics of what food goes through the official channels and how much calories are in there. Not always meeting the needs or not even the meagre plan.

Since there is also a [black market](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzmarkt#Beispiele) going strong this makes the simple number from the question highly dubious. The picture is a bit more complicated than that. The distribution of the necessary food was by far not righteous, not equal and not even enough over all. Hence the name "[hunger winter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungerwinter_1946/47)".

Rural people being better off than well connected city dwellers being better off than vulnerable people in the urban conglomerations.

The number given in the question is a highly time specific and locality specific data point zoning in to an average estimate.

For a more detailed breakdown you might consult local historians:

> [**Winter 1946/47**](https://www.regionalgeschichte.net/bibliothek/texte/aufsaetze/rothenberger-hungerjahre.html)
>
> Das Wohl und Wehe der städtischen Bevölkerung hing von der ausreichenden Zuteilung von Kartoffeln ab. Während es im Nordteil des Landes weitgehend gelang, die angekündigten 3 Ztr. pro Normalverbraucher zuzuteilen, schwankten in der Pfalz die Zuteilungen regional stark. Vor allem Ludwigshafen wurde unzureichend beliefert, und darum ist die Stadt im folgenden Frühjahr zum politischen Unruheherd geworden.
>
> In Erwartung amerikanischer Weizenlieferungen hatte die Militärregierung im September 1946 die Brotration wieder auf 300 g angehoben. Aber Mitte November mußte die Erhöhung zurückgenommen werden. Hoffnungslosigkeit breitete sich aus. Entscheidungen solcher Art hatten starke Rückwirkungen auf die Seelenlage der Menschen, Versorgungsschwankungen bewirkten ständig z.T. extreme psychische Wechsellagen. Sie haben sich in der Erinnerung der Zeitgenossen ebenso gut erhalten wie der Hunger.
>
> Gegen die Fettnot sammelte die Bevölkerung in den Wäldern Bucheckern; für 6 kg tauschten die offiziellen Sammelstellen 1 Liter Öl ein. Die Stimmungslage wurde bedrückend, als feststand, dass auch für diesen Winter keine Kohlenzuteilungen zu erwarten waren. Wegen Kohlenmangels stilliegende Bäckereien zeigten die Knappheit an. Die Menschen schlugen das ihnen zugeteilte Holz selbst in den Wäldern. Dann setzte im Dezember ein Winter ein, der zu den härtesten in diesem Jahrhundert zählt. Drei Monate Frost mit Temperaturen bis zu minus 20 Grad. Mosel, Nahe und Lahn waren zweimal zugefroren, am Rhein bildete sich eine Eisbarriere von St. Goar bis Mannheim, die die Schifffahrt stilllegte. Der Frost erlaubte keine Hamsterfahrten mehr. In den beschädigten Häusern mit ihren zugigen Fenstern sanken die Temperaturen nachts unter Null Grad. Aus Verzweiflung wanderte manches Klavier durch den Kamin. Die Sterblichkeitskurve nahm in diesen Monaten einen sprunghaften Anstieg von 11,4 im November auf 17,4 im Februar, jeweils bezogen auf 1.000 Einwohner.
>
> Gegen die Kälte richteten die Städte öffentliche Wärmehallen ein. Es wurden Steckrüben zum Strecken der Kartoffelvorräte ausgegeben. Mehr und mehr Menschen verpflegten sich in Volksküchen, weil der Hausbrand nicht zum Zubereiten des Mahles ausreichte.
>
> **Sommer 1947**
>
> Der Sommer 1947 stellte den Tiefpunkt in der Nachkriegsernährung dar. Im März hatte sich die Lage zunächst gebessert, als nach Ende der Frostperiode die Kartoffeltransporte wieder aufgenommen werden konnten und der Militärregierung erstmals Importe von Hülsenfrüchten gelangen, so dass der Kalorienabfall nicht mehr als die üblichen 10% betrug. Dann aber fiel wegen mangelhaften Saatgutes die lebenserhaltende Frühkartoffelernte schlecht aus. Die erwarteten Weizenimporte blieben aus. Das Brot wurde bis zur Hälfte mit Maismehl gestreckt; Deutschland hieß im Volksmund "Maisopotamien". **Die Kalorien sanken erstmals seit neun Monaten unter 1.000, im August 1947 unter 900, örtlich auf 600-700 pro Tag ab. In einer Resolution hielten die Betriebsräte von Annweiler der Landesregierung ihre Juli-Ration vor: 15 1/2 Pfund Brot, 340 g Fleisch, 125 g Käse und 200 g Linsen, aber keine Kartoffeln. Das ergab 594 Kalorien. Auf dem Schwarzen Markt stieg der Kartoffelpreis auf 600 RM pro Zentner an.**
>
> Die Ernte 1947 betrug nur noch 40% der Vorkriegsernten, weil die Böden inzwischen ausgelaugt waren und Hitze und Trockenheit dieses "tropischen" Sommers, des heißesten seit einem Vierteljahrhundert, ihnen die letzte Kraft raubte. Die Viehweiden verbrannten, die Kartoffeln erreichten oft nur die Größe von Tischtennisbällen. Im Januar 1948 würde die Ernte aufgezehrt sein.
>
> Die Leidensschwelle der Bevölkerung war – insbesondere nach dem zehrenden Winter – überschritten. Im Juli 1947 traten die Steinbrucharbeiter von Kusel in den Hungerstreik, im August gingen in Ludwigshafen und Kaiserslautern die Menschen auf die Straße. Die ersten Anzeichen eines grundlegenden Wandels der Stimmungslage und des Selbstgefühls der Menschen wurden erkennbar, die sich im Frühjahr 1948 verstärkt fortsetzten. Die Neigung zum schuldbewussten Gedulden wich zunehmend Empörung, Protest und Drohung mit Gewalt. Betriebe in der Pfalz und in Rheinhessen meldeten Abwesenheitsquoten bis zu 30%, weil die Menschen es für nutzbringender hielten, ihre Kräfte für Hamsterfahrten einzusetzen. Gewichtsmessungen in Industriebetrieben ergaben Untergewichte bis zu 10 kg.
>
> Die Militärregierung ging mit rigorosen Maßnahmen gegen Lebensmittelhinterziehungen der Bauern vor, was die Städter beruhigte. Vor allem verringerte sie durch Massenschlachtungen den Viehstapel. Das erhöhte die Fleischration der Normalverbraucher, stellte aber eine Hypothek für die Milch- und Fettversorgung im folgenden Jahr dar.

Translation of the key passage in bold:

> For the first time in nine months the allotted calories sank below 1000. In August 1947 they dropped below 900, locally even to 600–700   calories a day. In one resolution, Annweiler's work councils presented their July rations to the state government: 15 half pounds of bread, 340 grams of meat, 125 grams of cheese and 200 grams of lentils, but no potatoes. That  resulted in 594 calories. On the black market, the price of potatoes rose to 600 Reichsmark per 50 kilograms.

**Summary**

These are largely the official numbers that were planned to be granted to the populace, slightly corrected to actual calories delivered on average mainly for the urban consumers. While many people did die from malnutrition and starvation, these numbers were not as low across the board for all. The former and future elite, the very thrifty and the rural citizens did a bit better than these numbers suggest.

> How is historical “average calorie consumption” data from eighty years ago estimated?

To be very blunt: By just using the numbers calculated back then.